# How to change encoding (using latin encoding) in pyreadr Python

Tags: python, encoding, rdata, latin

I am trying to read an RData file in Python with the package `pyreadr`, but the default encoding is 'utf-8'. I need to change it into 'latin' because when I launch the following command

`pyreadr.read_r('Input/myFile.RData')`

I get the following error:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 30: invalid start byte`

The `pyreadr.read_r` function does not have the `encoding` input parameter, so I do not know how to fix it. Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is currently not possible. From the [README](https://github.com/ofajardo/pyreadr#known-limitations) in the known limitations section:

> Cannot read RData or rds files in encodings other than utf-8.

This feature would need to be suported by the underlying C library [librdata](https://github.com/WizardMac/librdata/issues). You can open an issue in librdata suggesting to implement this feature, together with a sample file.